# Flutter: how to detect changes in an object that is in another object and change the widget based on that?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some classes:

```
class School {
  ClassRoom classRoom;
  bool isClosed;
}

class ClassRoom {
  HeadTeacher headTeacher;
  bool isClosed;
}

class HeadTeacher {
  bool isSick;
}
```

I have a Stream that is listing the `School`s. It is updated if the Schools table is updated in the database.

I build a list of widgets based on this stream. I would like to add an extra text/widget in case the Scool closed or the ClassRoom closed or the HeadTeacher is sick:

```
...
if (School.closed || ClassRoom.closed || HeadTeacher.isSick) Text("Stay at home"),
...
```

The problem is that it might happen that the HeadTeacher is Sick, the `Text` widget get generated and after some seconds the HeadTeacher is no longer sick -> the `Text` widget should disappear.

But since the variable in HeadTeacher changed, it has no idea about it since the stream is looking for changes in the `School` and not in the ClassRoom or in the HeadTeacher objects.

What would be a way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share code about how you are building the stream.